# Why importing only class in Python?

Tags: python, namespaces

I am C++ developer and new to Python.

I have read code like this,

```
from pywinauto import Application
```

Now, pywinauto is namespace and Application is class. What if I write,

```
import pywinauto
```

What problem it creates, it is just because we do not want to pollute global namespace, or any deeper meaning.

In C# and C++ I have seen Importing nested namespaces, but explicit class can also be imported in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of personal preference. If you want to write `pywinauto.Application` rather than `Application` every time you refer to the class then you can do that. Each module has it's own namespace so if you also defined an `Application` in the module that you were importing `pywinauto.Application` into then the choice would be obvious.

Comment: Does that mean, if I only write import pywinauto,  I need to use Application as pywinauto.Application, even if no conflict with other modules?

Comment: @pranitkothari yes you have to use `pywinauto.Application` if you import the whole pywinauto module.
Check this page in the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) for more info.